# Get latest unique params from ArrayList

Tags: java, java-7

I have the following data:

```
class Param{
    Long id;
    String name;
    Date date;
}

List<Param> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add(new Param (1L, "AAA", new date(2020,11,1)));
myList.add(new Param (1L, "AAA", new date(2019,11,1)));
myList.add(new Param (2L, "BBB", new date()));
```

I want to get a new List that contains only objects with unique id and name with latest date:

```
e.g: myNewList content: [{1L, "AAA", new date(2020,10,1)},{2L, "BBB", new date()}]
```

My problem is that I should do it without override equals() and hashcode() methods of Param class and without using Java streams (this is a legacy project that uses Java 7).

Is there any efficient way to get the latest unique params without updating Param class?

Comment: If you cannot override the Param class equals and hashCode methods, do you think you could extend it? Like, create a ChildParam extends Param and then override the methods just for the purpose of getting this new list?

Comment: You can create a `Map<Param,Param>` with a custom comparator that only compares the the `id` and `name` fields of the `Param` class. Then iterate over `myList`. If the current param does not already exist in the map, add it as key and value. If it already exists then replace the value at this param if the current param is older than the stored on. In the end, collect the values from the map and be done.
EDIT: Actually you can probably do even better: Sort `myList` using a custom compmarator and then scan through the sorted list, keeping only the last element for each id/name pair.

Comment: or use any data structure S (Map, List or whatever) where you can check if element with some id is contained.  then iterate over the list, for each element i check if i either is not in S or is in S, but the date is < i.date. then add or replace.

Comment: do you want efficiency in terms of runtime or development time or both?

Comment: runtime is important for me as well